# How C++ compiler knows the length of an array

Tags: c++, c++11

For example, in the main function, I can write `int arr[42]`, and I can use range for loop without indicating its length `for (auto i : arr)`. It works well. Compiler will know its length.

If I pass this array to another function, such as `void foo(int arr[])`, I cannot use range for loop because the compiler doesn't know its length.

After all, if I have this template `template<class T, size_t N> void arr_init(T (&foo)[N])`, I can call it by `arr_init(x)`. Obviously, the compiler calls `arr_init(int (&)[42])`.

I guess the compiler knows the length of array through its declaration `int[42]`. Am I right? I've got this question when I use range for loop and learn templates. I haven't met such problem before, when I was using C.

Comment: It might help if you consider that `void foo(int arr[])` is absolutely no different to declaring `void foo(int* arr)`.

Comment: why don't you make the function look like `foo(int * arr, int arrSize)`?

Comment: @peppe The range-based for does not use `std::begin`/`std::end`. It is specified to behave in a similar way to those function templates.

Comment: @user657267, @Ubica. It's just an example to show the compiler's behavior. I know actually I'm passing a single pointer when I use this function `foo(int *arr)`. Thanks :)

Comment: @LeeRancher You're passing a single pointer in *both* of those functions, `arr` is a pointer regardless of whether you declare it as `int* arr` or `int arr[]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array type `T[N]` is distinct from the array type `T[M]` for a type `T` and two distinct sizes `N` and `M`. So, the length of an array is built into the type.

OTOH, arrays are automatically [decayed](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array#Array_to_pointer_decay) to pointers in a function calls argument list. In other words, there is no distinction between these three function signatures:

```
int func(int []);
int func(int[5]);
int func(int[10]);
int func(int*);
```

All the above signatures are simply taking an `int*`. If you want to preserve the array type, you need to create a function which takes an array reference as an argument. That is exactly what you achieve in your example `template<class T, size_t N> void arr_init(T (&foo)[N])`. Inside `arr_init`, `foo` behaves like an array because it is a reference to an array type.

For an array `arr` of type `T[N]`, the [range-based `for`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) uses the expressions `arr` and `arr+N` as the start and end points, respectively.

For class types, member functions `begin` and `end`, if present, are used to determine the endpoints, failing which the non-member overloads, `begin` and `end` are used.

(`begin` and `end`, as opposed to `std::begin` and `std::end`, since the generic usage of `begin` and `end` in the standard library is like this:

```
using std::begin;
begin(...);
using std::end;
end(...);
```

This allows ADL to find user-defined `begin` and `end` overloads.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're right. This is because the compiler knows the size of objects defined in the same translation unit.

In fact, you don't need to use a range for loop to see similar behavior; you can use plain `sizeof`.

foo.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int a[];

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(a));
}
```

bar.c:

```
int a[50];
```

Now to test:

```
gcc foo.c bar.c
> foo.c: In function 'main':
> foo.c:7:23: error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'int[]'
```

Comment: Thanks, using `sizeof` is really a good idea.

Comment: Sorry, but I've no !dea how this answers the _entire_ post, but since OP has accepted it, I assume (s)/he may have simply copy pasted some stuffs from websites just out of curiosity

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you pass an array by reference, you can deduce it's size (remember that arrays **are not pointers**). So the functions `std::begin()` and `std::end()`, which are used by the range-based for, are probably overloaded like this for arrays

```
namespace std
{
    template<typename T, std::size_t N>
    T* std::begin(T (&arr)[N])
    {
        return arr;
    }

    template<typename T, std::size_t N>
    T* std::end(T (&arr)[N])
    {
        return arr + N;
    }
}
```

Arrays decay to pointers only when passed by value, like

```
void f(int arr[256]){...}
```

which is syntactic sugar for

```
void f(int* arr){...}
```

PS: it looks like the range-based `for` doesn't use `std::begin` and `std::end`, since the compiler knows the size of the array at compile time (as mentioned by @T.C.). So the above code is just for demonstration purposes ;)

See **6.5.4** of the standard for more details about the range-based `for`:

> > In each case, a range-based for statement is equivalent to

```
    {
       auto && __range = range-init;
       for ( auto __begin = begin-expr,
                  __end = end-expr;
             __begin != __end;
              ++__begin ) { 
           for-range-declaration = *__begin; 
           statement
       } 
    }
```

> **6.4.3/1** if _RangeT is an array type, *begin-expr* and *end-expr* are *__range* and *__range + __bound*, respectively, where *__bound* is the array bound. If *_RangeT* is an array of unknown size or an array of incomplete type, the program is ill-formed;

Comment: The range-based for does not use `std::begin` and `std::end`.

Comment: @T.C. didn't know this, how does it work then? I skimmed through some S.O. and it looks like you can get into some ADL problems if using `std::begin/end` by range-based `for`s.

Comment: I see that 6.5.4/1 describes the mechanism... Not entirely clear but I guess it uses some similar kind of size deduction for *begin-expr* and *end-expr*

Comment: The compiler knows the size of array types. It's specified that way for arrays and classes with `begin()/end()` members in part so that you don't have to include `<iterator>` if you just want to iterate over it.